# Как записать значение в пользовательское поле при изменении статуса заказа?

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет!

Нужно забрать сумму заказа и записать значение в пользовательское поле(объет USER) при смене статуса заказа. Для этого в init.php добавляю такой код:

```
\Bitrix\Main\EventManager::getInstance()->addEventHandler('sale', 'OnSaleStatusOrderChange', ['Handler', 'OnSaleStatusOrderChange']);

class Handler {
  function OnSaleStatusOrderChange($event)
  {
    $parameters = $event->getParameters();
    if ($parameters['VALUE'] === 'P')
    {
      /** @var \Bitrix\Sale\Order $order */
      $order = $parameters['ENTITY'];
      /*
       здесь как то нужно записать значение в поле
       */
    }

    return new \Bitrix\Main\EventResult(
      \Bitrix\Main\EventResult::SUCCESS
    );
  }
}
```

Тип поля: строка. Само поле относится к пользователю. Помогите разобраться

Answer (score 1):

```
$obUserTypeEntity = new CUserTypeEntity();

// получить список пользовательских полей
$rsList = $obUserTypeEntity->GetList($arSort, $arFilter);

// обновить метаданные пользовательского поля
$obUserTypeEntity->Update($ID, $arFields);
```

Для обновления значений необходимо использовать классы СUserTypeString, CUserTypeInt и подобные. С версии 20.0.700 рекомендуется использовать классы  ядра D7 https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_d7/bitrix/main/userfield/introduction.php

Answer (score 0):

Может кому пригодится, решил так:

```
\Bitrix\Main\EventManager::getInstance()->addEventHandler('sale', 'OnSaleStatusOrderChange', ['Handler', 'OnSaleStatusOrderChange']);

class Handler {
  function OnSaleStatusOrderChange($event)
  {
    $parameters = $event->getParameters();
    if ($parameters['VALUE'] === 'P')
    {
      /** @var \Bitrix\Sale\Order $order */
      $order = $parameters['ENTITY'];
      $userID = $order->getField("USER_ID"); // получаем ID пользователя
      $orderPrice = $order->getField("PRICE"); // получаем сумму заказа

      //получаем пользовательское поле для записи
      global $USER;

      $filter = Array("ID" => $userID, "ACTIVE"=> "Y");
      $arParams["SELECT"] = array( "UF_BONUS_SUM");

      $rsUsers = CUser::GetList(($by="personal_phone"), ($order="desc"), $filter, $arParams); 
      while ($arUser = $rsUsers->Fetch()) {
         $oldSum = $arUser["UF_BONUS_SUM"];
      }

      $bonusSum = $oldSum + $orderPrice; // сумма заказа + сумма, которая уже записана в пользовательское поле
      $user = new CUser;
      $fields = Array(
        "UF_BONUS_SUM" => $bonusSum,
        );
      $user->Update($userID, $fields); // обновляем поле

      //Bitrix\Main\Diag\Debug::writeToFile(array($order ),"","/log_new.txt");

    }

    return new \Bitrix\Main\EventResult(
      \Bitrix\Main\EventResult::SUCCESS
    );
  }
}
```